# how to read Realtime firebase data (ref.on is not a function )?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

use next.js

**update** and **set** work without problems, but when I want to read using **on**, an error occurs, in the settings **firebase** checked for me **read** and **write** = **true**

```
import { getDatabase,ref,set,once,on,update,onChildAdded} from 'firebase/database';


const reference = ref(db, 'room/' + 'new');
  
  // get support data from firebase
  reference.on('value',function (snapshot) {
      console.log("In Value");
      console.log(snapshot.val());
  }, function(error) {
      console.error(error);
  });
```

I get an error

```
reference.on is not a function at startSubmit
```

[image]

**my firebase**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `onValue()` function in the new Modular SDK to listen for updates at the database reference. Try refactoring the code like this:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const reference = ref(db, 'room/' + 'new');

onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val(); 
  console.log(data)
});
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_2) for more information.